# sequence limits - correctness of the adjustment

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to ask why the following modification of the example is not allowed $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+2+ \cdots + 2^n}{1+5+ \cdots + 5^n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2^n}{5^n}\right)\cdot \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{2}{2^n}+.....+1\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{5^n}+\frac{5}{5^n}+.....+1\right)}$$
and similarly

$$\displaystyle\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{3n+1}{4n+5}\right) ^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\cdot\left(\frac{1 + \frac{1}{3n}}{1 + \frac{5}{4n}}\right)^n$$

For these two examples, I am not concerned with the calculation, but rather with describing why this procedure is wrong.

Comment: Both cases are perfectly correct and allowed. Why not? Now, whether it will make the limits' calculation easier is way another matter...

Comment: Why do you think there’s something wrong?

Comment: We have banned these constructions at school, they call it "partial limitation".

Comment: What you do in your school is one thing, but being mathematically right or wrong is, apparently, another. I suppose they banned because you may be lured to make arithmetic of limits and that is forbiden in both cases.

Comment: I can ask what you mean by lured to make arithmetic of limits

Comment: Any valid (like don't divide by zero) algebraic manipulation of expression under limit is allowed. So what you have done is correct. I wonder why your school/teacher is prohibiting that.

Comment: @martin19875 With such a decomposition you might be tempted to use arithmetic of limits, and it is this what your teacher must be trying to avoid. Yet forbidding it, as if it were incorrect, is not the way I'd do it....as it is mathematically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually evaluate the limits I'd go as follows:

$$\frac{1+2+\ldots+2^n}{1+5+\ldots+5^n}=\frac{\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2}}{\frac{1-5^{n+1}}{1-5}}=4\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-5^{n+1}}=4\left(\frac25\right)^{n+1}\;\frac{\frac1{2^{n+1}}-1}{\frac1{5^{n+1}}-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}4\cdot0\cdot1=0$$

As for the second one:

$$\left(\frac{3n+1}{4n+5}\right)^n=\frac1{\left(\frac43\right)^n}\left(\frac{3n+1}{3n+\frac{15}4}\right)^n=\frac1{\left(\frac43\right)^n}\left(1-\frac{\frac{11}4}{3n+\frac{15}4}\right)^n=$$

$$=\frac1{\left(\frac43\right)^n}\left[\left(1-\frac{\frac{11}4}{3n+\frac{15}4}\right)^{3n+\frac{15}4}\right]^{-2n-\frac{15}4}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\cdot0=0$$

Comment: I was more concerned with what was wrong with those procedures than with the calculation. In addition, the second example could be solved using the theorem on the limit of a tight sequence.

Comment: @martin19875  I don't know what a "tight" sequence is. The problem is : in the first case, the number of elements in the sum both in the numerator and denominator depends on $\;n\;$ (i.e., it is not a fixed, constant number of times) and thus arithmetic of limits doesn't apply. In the second case is similar, but then you have a limit of the form $\;1^\infty\;$ and this can be anything from zero to infty, so we cannot directly apply arithmetic in the basis

Comment: So if I generally have something on n, then I can't use the theorems about limit arithmetic?

Comment: @martin19875 That is correct. For example, you could get aberrations like $$1=\frac nn=\frac1n+\frac1n+\ldots+\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0+0+\ldots+0=0$$ which of course is nonsense. We must be very careful with this.

Comment: ok, thank you  :)

Comment: For the second one we can use the fact that expression in parentheses tends to $3/4$ (something with absolute value less than $1$) and then raising this to power $n$ tends to $0$. Maybe that's what the asker @martin19875 meant by a tight sequence. But its just a guess.